# How to run maven from eclipse with the -e switch

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, exec-maven-plugin

Is it possible to execute the exec goal with the exec-maven-plugin with the -e switch? I am getting a `MojoExecutionException`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what plugin you are using? Eclipse IAM or m2eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

right click the project > run as >  `maven build...` > supply goal there with `-e` switch

**Note** 3 dots after `maven build...`

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project and Run as -> Run Configurations...

[image]

Add the -e (or other switches for eg. -X, etc.) in the Goals input box. If you already have some goals add a space and then put your switch.

[image]